# React native use propType from native component

Tags: react-native

I have `CustomText` component that accepts `align` as one of the props.

```
const alignPropType = PropTypes.oneOf(
   ['auto' /*default*/, 'left', 'right', 'center', 'justify']
)
CustomText.proptypes = {
   align: alignPropType
}
```

Native `Text` Component has following propType validator for `textAlign`

```
PropTypes.oneOf(
   ['auto' /*default*/, 'left', 'right', 'center', 'justify']
)
```

So I want use `textAlign` propType from native `Text` component for `CustomText` Component.

That will look something like this:

```
CustomText.proptypes = {
   align:Text.propTypes.style.textAlign
}
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: @VahidBoreiri I updated question, can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question well, your component will be like this:

```
export default class CustomText extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text textAlign={this.props.align}></Text>
    );
  }
}

CustomText.proptypes = {
   align: propTypes.oneOf(['auto' , 'left', 'right', 'center', 'justify'])
}
```